# Chrome debugger: hover a variable in js debugger but cannot see the value anymore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, devtools

**Chrome Version**       : Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**OS**                   : Windows 10 Pro

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Add break-point on variable
2. hit the break-point
3. when break-point occurs hover on variable which contain value.

[image: PFA for detail issue]

**What is the expected result?**

hover a variable in js debugger and must see the value of variable.

**What happens instead?**

hover a variable in js debugger but not seeing the value of variable.

Comment: This is a bug. It'll be fixed in the next update of Chrome. Meanwhile you can use Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working with following latest version:

**Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

Comment: its not working in latest Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). any solution?

Comment: wait for next update of Chrome. Meanwhile you can use Chrome Canary.